# PHP image thumbnail creation not working with high resolution images

Tags: php, thumbnails, image-upload

A website I'm working on has a functionality to upload images. After uploading, a thumbnail is generated and saved to the 'uploads' folder. It all works perfectly until I try to upload panoramas taken with an iPhone. These images are about 11,000 px wide which I think is the problem.

First question: What variable or parameter limits the creation of thumbnails? Is this issue fixable?

Second question: I've put the part that stopped working in a try & catch but the php code just doesn't execute anything after the thumbnail creating part. How do I make it do something else when this part of the code is not working?

I think the problem lies somewhere within the imagecopyresampled but I'm not sure. I hope someone has more experience with this than I do.

```
$ds          = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
$storeFolder = '../uploads/';

if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $targetPath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . $ds. $storeFolder . $ds;
    $date = new DateTime();
    $newFileName = $date->getTimestamp().$_FILES['file']['name'];
    $targetFile =  $targetPath. $newFileName;
    move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);

    $thumbStoreFolder = '../thumbs/';
    $thumbPath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . $ds. $thumbStoreFolder . $ds;
    $thumbnail = $thumbPath.'thumb'.$newFileName;
    list($width,$height) = getimagesize($targetFile);
    if($width >= $height) {
        $thumb_width = 300;
        $ratio = $width / $thumb_width;
        $thumb_height = $height / $ratio;
    } else {
        $thumb_height = 300;
        $ratio = $height / $thumb_height;
        $thumb_width = $width / $ratio;
    }
    $thumb_create = imagecreatetruecolor($thumb_width,$thumb_height);
    $source = imagecreatefromjpeg($targetFile);
    imagecopyresampled($thumb_create,$source,0,0,0,0,$thumb_width,$thumb_height,$width,$height);
    imagejpeg($thumb_create,$thumbnail);
}
```

Comment: You are probably just running out of memory due to the size of the image.  Raise the PHP memory limit.

Comment: What is the maximum file upload size in your application? This may also be limiting.

Comment: On the php.ini file I have upload_max_filesize=128M and memory_limit=128M. I've set them both to 1024M for testing purposes but still I have the same problem.

Comment: The strange thing is that for example an image with dimensions 12000x4000 of not even 10MB doesn't work and an image with a smaller resolution (5000x3500) but bigger file size of 16,5MB works perfectly fine.